# How do templates work in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I've been looking at this example and looking through google to no avail. I don't understand how `popover-template` works. Is it Angular's templating system? I couldn't find any documentation on this, so I thought I'll turn to the community. How can I similarly create my own template?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

 <head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="bootstrap-ui.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@2.3.2" data-semver="2.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div style="padding-bottom: 400px"></div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="tc">Sample:</label>
      <div class="controls">
       <div class="input-prepend">
        <input placeholder="Enter end date.." type="text" class="input-small" ng-model="entity.endDate" name="endDate" />
        <button type="button" class="btn" ng-model="$parent.entity.endDate" popover-template="datepicker-test.html">
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
      </button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) from angular-ui's bootstrap sub-project:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-model="$parent.entity.endDate" popover-template="datepicker-test.html">
```

the corresponding Javascript is inbootstrap-ui.js:

```
.directive( 'popoverTemplate', [ '$tooltip', function ( $tooltip ) {
    return $tooltip( 'popoverTemplate', 'popover', 'click' );
}]);
```

The project is here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap

Comment: Maarten, I'm little confused...I can't find popoverTemplate directive in [ui-boostrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) code...but the weird thing is this [link](http://embed.plnkr.co/Zxm90d/preview), it seems to use the same version but with that directive!...why?

Comment: ok. I think that's the [answer](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/1391#issuecomment-32494143): temporary workaround, while the official feature is not available...